# como obtener el valor desde ajax a php?

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#estados_visa').on('change', function(){
        var distritos= $('#estados_visa').val();


        console.log(distritos)
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'cargar_distritos.php',
            data:{dato1: distritos}
        })
        .done(function(lista_rep){
            $('#distritos_visa').html(lista_rep);
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert('error al cargar las listas');
        });
    })
});
```

Este es mi cargar_distritos

```
function getListDis(){
$con = getCon();
$id = $_POST['dato1'];
$query = "SELECT commerce_brand, commerce_region, commerce_district FROM commerc WHERE commerce_region = $id GROUP BY commerce_district  ORDER BY commerce_district, commerce_region";
$result = $con->query($query);
$listas_distritos = '<option value="">Elige una opcion</option>';
$listas_distritos .= '';
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$listas_distritos .= "<option value='$row[commerce_region]'>$row[commerce_district]</option>";
}
return $listas_distritos;
}
```

Comment: En donde llamas a la funcion `getListDis()`

Comment: despues de la funcion @alanfcm

Answer (score 2):

En PHP las funciones no se llaman solas.

Si todo lo que tienes en el archivo PHP es lo que muestras, ese código no se estará ejecutando nunca porque `getListDis()` nunca se llama.

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Verificas la variable del POST.
- Si existe, se la pasas a la función, si no existe muestras un mensaje de error o lo que sea.

Por ejemplo:

```
$dato=(empty($_POST['dato1'])) ? NULL : $_POST['dato1'];

if ($dato){
    getListDis($dato);
}else{
    return "Error, no se posteó dato1";
}

function getListDis($id){
    $con = getCon();
    $query = "
               SELECT commerce_brand, commerce_region, commerce_district 
               FROM commerc 
               WHERE commerce_region = $id 
               GROUP BY commerce_district  
               ORDER BY commerce_district, commerce_region";
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $listas_distritos = '<option value="">Elige una opcion</option>';
    $listas_distritos .= '';
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $listas_distritos .= "<option value='$row[commerce_region]'>$row[commerce_district]</option>";
    }
    return $listas_distritos;
}
```

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**
>
> Tu consulta es altamente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.
>   Conviene que implementes consultas preparadas para evitar ese grave
>   riesgo.